# PHP doesn't fetch all rows from my database query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this code below:

```
if(isset($_POST['period'])){
    $query_str = "SELECT `id` FROM `orders` WHERE `status` = 'Send' AND `date` BETWEEN '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-$_POST['period'])."'  AND  '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())."'  ";
    echo $query_str;
    $query = mysql_query($query_str) or die(mysql_error());
    $arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    var_dump($arr);

}
```

As result I have these two strings:

```
// this value of $query_str
SELECT `id` FROM `orders` WHERE `status` = 'Send' AND `date` BETWEEN '2015-06-04 03:11:08'  AND  '2015-06-11 03:11:08' 

// var_dump of my $arr
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "25"
}
```

This result is wrong, but when I am copying `$uqery_str` value and put it into phpMyAdmin I have 3 results.

```
25,26,27 // this is right
```

Can anybody explain what is wrong?

Comment: Hopefully it's the gods striking down your code for still using `mysql_query` in 2015. (Don't know for sure; i literally stopped reading the question when i saw it.)

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Comment: It was late night when I worked and I did this stupid mistake... All ok. Thnx for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you only fetch the first row. Put your fetch call into a while loop to fetch all rows, e.g.

```
$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
var_dump($arr);
```

to:

```
while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    var_dump($arr);
}
```

`$query` is a resource and with [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) you fetch row by row from the resource. As from the manual:

> **Returns an associative array** that corresponds to the **fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead**.

Also since we are here I give you a *good night story* for today:

`mysql_*` is deprecated and is removed in new versions of PHP. So I would highly recommend you to look into [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_* prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Also keep in mind that mysql is deprecated (since PHP 5.5.0) and everyone is advised to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Great, may OPs dreams be _improved_ ;)